# Modifying Request Header in WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, access-control

In my IOS app I have a requirement where every request to the server should contain a specific HTTP header. Its not just on the first request but all subsequent requests should contain the header.

For that I am intercepting the request   using the delegate,

```
-(void) webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler{

if(([navigationAction.request.URL.host rangeOfString:kUSiteRegx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound) &&
                            [navigationAction.request valueForHTTPHeaderField:kHttpRequestHeader] == nil){
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        [webView loadCustomRequest:navigationAction.request];
        return;
    }
}
```

Here I cancel the original request and make a new request appending the header to the original header like given below.

```
-(WKNavigation*)loadCustomRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request{
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [request mutableCopy];
    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *versionString = [kHttpRequestPrefix stringByAppendingString:version];
    [req setValue:versionString forHTTPHeaderField:kHttpRequestHeader];
    return [self loadRequest:req];
}
```

Now this is preventing my request to break and the error it reports is,

> xmlhttprequest cannot load due to access control checks

How can I overcome this one?